# Non-overlapping rolling windows in pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create non-overlapping rolling or sliding window in pandas groupby

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame( {'a1':['A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B'],'a2':[1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2], 'b':[1,2,5,5,5,4,6,2]})
```

For overlapping rolling window, I can do this

```
df1.groupby(['a1','a2']).rolling(2).mean()
```

But is there any way to make it non-overlapping?

The output should be like this

```
pd.DataFrame('a1':['A','B','B','B','B'],'a2':[1,1,2,2,2],'b':[1.5,NaN,5,5,NaN])
```

**Explanation**

When `a1` is `A` and `a2` is `1`, the value of b is `1` and `2`. Adding both results in `1.5`.
When `a1` is `B` and `a2` is `1`, the value of `b` is `5`. As the value of `b` is less than the length of the sliding window, we got `NaN`.
When `a1` is `B` and `a2` is `2`, the value of b is `5,5,4,6,2`. As sliding window is `2`, so adding `(5+5)/2=5`, `(4+6)/2=5`. And last value is `NaN` as length is less than sliding window.

Comment: Could you add the output?

Comment: @DaniMesejo i added the sample output

Comment: "For overlapping rolling window, I can do this" You can't. It gives an error.

Comment: @AmiTavory no, it did not give any error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, one approach (not very elegant), is to do:

```
def non_overlapping_mean(x, window=2):
    return x.groupby(np.arange(len(x)) // window).apply(lambda x: np.nan if len(x) < 2 else x.mean())


res = df1.groupby(['a1', 'a2'])['b'].apply(non_overlapping_mean).droplevel(-1).reset_index()
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
  a1  a2    b
0  A   1  1.5
1  B   1  NaN
2  B   2  5.0
3  B   2  5.0
4  B   2  NaN
```

The main idea is to groupby into consecutive chunks, and is done here:

```
x.groupby(np.arange(len(x)) // window)
```